# How to remove a url pattern from spring security authentication?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I need to allow access to specific controllers bypassing Spring Security authentication, but I'm not sure why Spring Security still considers these URLs as protected. I've noticed the issue because every time I get a 401 response.

In debug mode I checked that requests still are being processed by the filter provided by `restAuthenticationFilter()`, even though these are theoretically public URLs.

Can anyone guess what I'm doing wrong, please?

I appreciate your help

My config class:

```
class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private static final RequestMatcher PUBLIC_URLS = new OrRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/authentication/**"));
  private static final RequestMatcher PROTECTED_URLS = new NegatedRequestMatcher(PUBLIC_URLS);

  @Override
  public void configure(final WebSecurity web) {
    web
      .ignoring()
        .requestMatchers(PUBLIC_URLS)
        .antMatchers("/v2/api-docs",
            "/configuration/ui",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/configuration/security",
            "/swagger-ui.html",
            "/webjars/**",
            "/authentication/**");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
      .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
        .and()
      .exceptionHandling()
        // this entry point handles when you request a protected page and you are not yet
        // authenticated
        .defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
        .and()
      .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthProv())
      .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
      .authorizeRequests()
        .requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS).authenticated()
        .and()
      .csrf().disable()
      .formLogin().disable()
      .httpBasic().disable()
      .logout().disable();
  }

... some other beans
```

My controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/authentication")
@FieldDefaults(level = PRIVATE, makeFinal = true)
@AllArgsConstructor(access = PACKAGE)
final class AuthenticationController {
  @NonNull
  IUserAuthenticationService authservice;
  @Autowired
  GerenciadorUsuariosIntegracao users;

  @PostMapping("/login")
  @ApiResponses(value = {
            @ApiResponse(code=400, message = "Bad Request", response = ExceptionResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code=401, message = "Unauthorized", response = ExceptionResponse.class),
            @ApiResponse(code=200, message = "OK", response = SuccessLoginResponse.class)
     })
  ResponseEntity<Object> login(@RequestBody UsuarioAPI usuario) {
      
     LocalDateTime horaAtual = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo"));
     Optional<String> token =  authservice.login(usuario.username, usuario.password);
     if (token.isPresent()) {
        SuccessLoginResponse sucessResponse = new SuccessLoginResponse(horaAtual, token.get());
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(sucessResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
     }
     else { 
        ExceptionResponse exceptionResponse = new ExceptionResponse(horaAtual.toLocalTime(), "credenciais inválidas");
        return new ResponseEntity<Object>(exceptionResponse, HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
     }
  }
  
  @PostMapping("/registrarusuario")
  String register(@RequestBody UsuarioAPI usuario) {
      ApiUser usuariopersistido = (ApiUser) users.registrarNovoUsuario(usuario);
    return usuariopersistido.toString();
  }
}
```

I also tried the first approach recommended.... still same result

```
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        final String[] SWAGGER_AUTH_WHITELIST = {
                "/v2/api-docs",
                "/configuration/ui",
                "/swagger-resources/**",
                "/configuration/security",
                "/swagger-ui.html",
                "/webjars/**",
                "/authentication/**"
        };  
    
    http
      .sessionManagement()
        .sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS)
        .and()
      .exceptionHandling()
        // this entry point handles when you request a protected page and you are not yet
        // authenticated
        //.defaultAuthenticationEntryPointFor(forbiddenEntryPoint(), PROTECTED_URLS)
        .and()
      .authenticationProvider(tokenAuthProv())
      .addFilterBefore(restAuthenticationFilter(), AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.class)
      .authorizeRequests()
        .mvcMatchers("/authentication/login").permitAll()
        .mvcMatchers("/authentication/registrarusuario").permitAll()
        .mvcMatchers(SWAGGER_AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
        //.requestMatchers(PROTECTED_URLS)
      .anyRequest()
        .authenticated()
        .and()
      .csrf().disable()
      .formLogin().disable()
      .httpBasic().disable()
      .logout().disable();
}
```

Comment: Show your `restAuthenticationFilter` class. Does it return 401?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have added `.authorizeRequests()` in the wrong order. `authorizeRequests()` order is important, the `.authenticated()` must come first.

```
.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
.and()
.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/authentication/login").permitAll()
.and()
....
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually configure these endpoints inside the `configure` method that has the `HttpSecurity` parameter. You can configure a list of endpoints to be permitted or a subset, according to the HTTP method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    final String[] SWAGGER_AUTH_WHITELIST = {
            "/swagger-ui/**",
            "/swagger-resources/**",
            "/v3/api-docs",
    };

    // Set permissions on endpoints
    http.authorizeRequests()
            // public endpoints (e.g. Swagger)
            .mvcMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers(SWAGGER_AUTH_WHITELIST).permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/products/**").permitAll()
            .mvcMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/users").permitAll()
            // private endpoints
            .anyRequest().authenticated();
}
```

Comment: Tested but it didn't work... I've edited my post with new information

Comment: Have you tried removing the first `configure` method? Otherwise, you have two configurations for the same thing, which is an issue. 

My code snippet is currently used in one of my projects and it works perfectly, both locally and in production.
Try to build a separate project for which you only include the security and web dependencies and try to get access to specific URLs. 
Also, there's no need to declare separate mvcMatchers for the `authentication` endpoint. You can simply say `.mvcMatchers("/authentication")` or `.mvcMatchers("/authentication/**")`